Larmor frequency in NMR for nucleus with spin greater than 1/2
I'm reading the theory about NMR and in most textbooks I can see that the Larmor  frequency achived as follow:
on the one hand from QM we know that
$$\Delta E = \hbar \omega $$
on the other hand, if the nucleus is in static magnetic field $B_0$ so the split in the two energy levels is
$$\Delta E = \hbar\gamma B_0 $$ so we have that $$\omega = \gamma B_0$$ which is the Larmor frequency but my question what happen in nuecleus with spin higher than 1/2? is it also have only 1 larmor frequency?

This confusion arises because Larmor frequency is used to refer to both, the precessional frequency of the macroscopic nuclear magnetisation vector, and the energy difference (in angular frequency units) of the nuclear spin states split by the Zeeman interaction. The energy difference between neighbouring states is always the same, independent of the two $m$, and the only allowed transitions are those with $\Delta m \pm 1$. Hence, the Larmor frequency does not depend on $S$ either, given that we consider only the Zeeman interaction. Nuclei with $S > 1/2$ do, however, experience quadrupolar interaction, which can cause relatively large deviations from the Zeeman-only energy-level structure.
